# Specify datacontext type on listbox ItemContainer in style

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, binding

In a `ListBox` I have a ItemContainer's `IsSelected` property bound to my ViewModel's `IsSelected` property using `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>` syntax.

It works fine, but I get a Resharper warning:

> Cannot resolve property 'IsSelected' in data context of type "FooSolution.BarViewModel".

How do I specify specify DataContext type on ListBox ItemContainer to get rid of this warning?

Here is the code. I have a `BarViewModel` class:

```
public ObservableCollection<FooViewModel> FooItems { get;set; }
```

`BarViewModel` is assigned to DataContext in the Control which contains the ListBox

and `FooViewModel` as follows:

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        return isSelected;
    }

    set
    {
        if (isSelected == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        isSelected = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelected);
    }
}
```

and XAML like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FooItems}" SelectionMode="Multiple">        
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

**Update**
I've tried setting `d:DataContext` using a setter, as suggested by HighCore, but unfortunatelly, it doesn't help and even breaks the build:

```
<Setter Property="d:DataContext" Value="{d:DesignInstance yourxmlns:yourItemViewModelClass}"/>
```

(Throws: Error  1   The tag 'DesignInstance' does not exist in XML namespace 'schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008';. Line 31 Position 50. )

**Update 2**
Finaly, the solution is to set `d:DataContext` on the style element itself (see my answer bellow):

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:FooViewModel }">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As pointed out by @HighCore the solution is to specify `d:DataContext` attribute from blend SDK, however, it worked only when set on a Style element itsself, not in the property setter:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:FooViewModel }">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This removes Resharper's warning and also changes binding Path when property is renaimed on the ViewModel. Cool!

Comment: I get the following error: Property 'DataContext' is not attachable to elements of type 'Style'. ¿?¿?¿

Comment: @somos , are you sure, you're using d:DataContext from blend SDK (this is a special attached prop to allow designer know about the type of VM in design time)

Comment: @Isantipov I also get the same Property 'DataContext' is not attachable to elements of type 'Style' error. Yes I am using d:DataContext from blend SDK.

Comment: @Kabbalah @Ignacio You need also add the following
`xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"`

Comment: @daVinci This gets added automatically by Visual Studio but doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: BEWARE: if you try using this construct, it will initially seem to work, but XAML Hot Reload will start silently failing from that moment on. Do not use this construct, use the one suggested by N. Kudryavtsev.

Answer (score 9):

Specifying `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance nmspc:Clz}"` with other attributes of `Style` tag **didn't** help me: R# / IntelliSense really stopped highlighting properties I was binding to *but the designer also showed me an error message instead of the view*.

The trick I found out is to specify `<d:Style.DataContext>` **inside** the `Style` tag. And it appeared to be so universal that it answers another question, about using interfaces as `d:DataContext`.

Here is my answer to that question with a small example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637478/5598194

Answer (score 3):

use `d:DataContext` like this:

```
<Setter Property="d:DataContext" Value="{d:DesignInstance yourxmlns:yourItemViewModelClass}"/>
```

You also need the following `xmlns`es added to the root element:

```
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d"
```

Comment: Interestingly: I keep getting the Resharper warning and the solution does not compile now: the following error is fired:Error 1 The tag 'DesignInstance' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008'. Line 31 Position 50. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add the `mc:Ignorable="d"`?

Comment: Yes, I did: doesn't help. Have you ever tried setting d:DataContext in a style?

Comment: I have found the solution: you need to specify d:DataContext on the Style element itself, not in the setter (see my responce bellow). I wouldn't fins this without your idea - thanks a lot!

Comment: I get a Error 1 Property 'DataContext' is not attachable to elements of type 'Setter' as well ... any idea? The namespace is working fine on other elements of the view ... ¿?

Comment: BEWARE: if you try using this construct, it will initially seem to work, but XAML Hot Reload will start silently failing from that moment on. Do not use this construct, use the one suggested by N. Kudryavtsev.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to previous answers: to get rid of error

> Property 'DataContext' is not attachable to elements of type 'Style'

add some dummy namespace

```
xmlns:ignore="designTimeAttribute"
```

and use it now instead of d:DataContext

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" ignore:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:FooViewModel }">
...
</Style>
```