# How to cast in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I happened to have the need to bind a Grid's `DataContext` to a listview's `SelectedItem` property

I could do that without any problem.... However, since the Listview's `SelectedItem` stores an object, the XAML editor does not know the type it is working with, which causes the following warning to be displayed : "Cannot resolve Property X in data context of type 'object'"

Is there any way to specify in one of the bindings which type an object is (i searched for WPF casting but found no pertinent resources)

Here is a relevant extract of my XAML :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding LoginScreens}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" SelectionMode="Single"/>
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListView}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       /*rows*/
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      /*Columns*/
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding NameFr}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Filename}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding SHA1}"/>
</Grid>
```

I tried the following syntax in the TextBox's bindings which didn't work :

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding (manifestEditor:LoginScreen.Filename)}"/>
```

But it causes an error to be thrown about a key being null in a ListDictionary, so either i'm missing something or it is not the right way to go.

**EDIT :**

I'd like as much as possible to only use XAML to handle this

Comment: This is because it doesn't know until runtime what the object will be (although you'd think it would in many cases). I tend to just ignore it.

Comment: Well, I just wondered since I know what kind of object the item will be if I could give it a hint

Comment: Does it bind correctly when you run it?

Comment: @mariocatch All bindings are working at runtime, I was just wondering if it was possible to avoid the warnings at design-time

Comment: But you are already binding to LoginScreens.  Why do you need to do this in XAML?  What is the big deal with Binding SelectedItem?

Comment: @Blam There is no big deal, as I stated all works fine, I just wondered how to avoid a warning, since it generally allows me to learn more about how to better use a language/feature

Comment: @Sidewinder94 Might be a design-time only issue, which might be resolved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231120/specify-datacontext-type-on-listbox-itemcontainer-in-style

Comment: @mariocatch It is a design time Issue, Olaru's answer worked great but it's great to have another alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. Just to add something new and useful here is another way of defining the binding to the SelectedItem:

```
    <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding LoginScreens}" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                  SelectionMode="Single"/>
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding LoginScreens}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NameFr}"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Filename}"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding SHA1}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem syncs the CurrentItem of the default CollectionView of the bound collection with the SelectedItem of your control and by choosing the DataContext of the Grid as the ObservableCollection LoginScreens, you will get the updates according to the ListView selection.

Answer (score 0):

Databind the SelectedItem to a ViewModel. Databind the DataGrid's datacontext to the same ViewModel. As long as the ViewModel knows what types it's working with, all should work well.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to avoid C# code on this one and stay in the XAML :) will add this precision in the question